# Distance calculation in Cloudant

Tags: node.js, mapreduce, geospatial, cloudant, euclidean-distance

Here is the problem I am trying to solve.

A client sends their current location which comes in via an API managed by a Node.js app. The Cloudant database stores a list of coordinates (a few thousand).

What would be the optimal way to get 
a) the list of all the coordinates AND
b) the distance of each of those coordinates from the client's location WHICH
c) fall within X km radius of the client's location

A geospatial index has already been created for those stored coordinates.

Speed and efficiency are key but sometimes these can be opposing qualities. If possible, I would much prefer to use the native functions within Cloudant instead of custom code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking on the site, it looks like there is already some pre-build geospatial stuff in cloudant:
https://docs.cloudant.com/geo.html#geospatial-indexing

Sometime in the past, I did this a bit different.  I did it with a search index:
https://docs.cloudant.com/search.html
This index would put out the lat & lng.  Then, to find any documents that were within 25 miles from some search point, you can write a lucene query that bounds the lat from [search_lat-25miles, search_lat+25miles] and lng from [search_lng-25miles, search_lat+25miles].
Using this approach I was able to do this with raw lat&lng. It looks like cloudant has some new functionality to make geospatial searches a little more straightforward too.

Comment: Cloudant Search is the way to go if you want to distances from the given point returned. [Cloudant Geo](https://docs.cloudant.com/geo.html) is a more flexible index in that it allows you to query by irregular polygon, but the db can't add that relative distance info to the response. Here's a tutorial https://examples.cloudant.com/simplegeo_places/_design/geo/search.html